Microsoft Graph Api Getting PasswordCreds and ordering them by endDateTime
I'm currently working with the Microsoft GraphApi and I've got the result I want for the most part, but I can't seem to sort them by the passwordCredentials/endDateTime. Now from my understanding is that it's a multi leve call because the Json query below shows that the dates are nesting in the passwordCredentials obj. IM trying to get the applications that are expiring first if that is even possible.
Microsoft explorer tool
Here is the query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=id,keyCredentials,passwordCredentials

json example of what I get when I
{
"value": [
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000001",
        "displayName": "account name 1",
        "passwordCredentials": [
            {
                "customKeyIdentifier": null,
                "displayName": "Testing 1",
                "endDateTime": "2023-11-15T20:55:22.571Z",
                "hint": "akW",
                "keyId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000001",
                "secretText": null,
                "startDateTime": "2023-05-19T19:55:22.571Z"
            },
            {
                "customKeyIdentifier": null,
                "displayName": null,
                "endDateTime": "2119-05-09T16:43:05.4628335Z",
                "hint": "P49",
                "keyId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000002",
                "secretText": null,
                "startDateTime": "2019-05-09T16:43:05.4628335Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000002",
        "displayName": "account name 2",
        "passwordCredentials": [
            {
                "customKeyIdentifier": null,
                "displayName": "Testing 2",
                "endDateTime": "2025-01-29T22:25:40.768Z",
                "hint": "9Oz",
                "keyId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000002",
                "secretText": null,
                "startDateTime": "2023-01-30T22:25:40.768Z"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}

I was thinking that I could add on the &$orderby= at the end to see if I could get something back and it give me this response.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=id,keyCredentials,passwordCredentials&$orderby=displayName

response:
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Sorting not supported for 'Application'.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2024-04-17T18:51:22",
        "request-id": "f31287e1-0105-463e-8611-b80c495ae67c",
        "client-request-id": "edcaa30c-6ee2-c876-b331-c7570345a5d1"
    }
  }
}


The Graph API supports sorting only on single values, passwordCredentials is a collection.
You will have to apply sorting on a client, or you can find a lot of PowerShell scripts how to find expiring client secrets.
https://www.joeyverlinden.com/find-expiring-client-secrets-using-graph-api-and-powershell/
To be able to sort application by single values (like displayName), you need to add $count=true query parameter and include the request header ConsistencyLevel with value eventual
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$select=id,keyCredentials,passwordCredentials&$orderby=displayName&$count=true

